# Segmentation fault on binary tree

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree, undefined-behavior, function-definition

I'm working on a program that searches through a program and outputs the number of times it comes across a number greater than or equal to the value specified in the parameter of the function. I have attached my code below, I see it traverses two of the values before a segmentation fault occurs. The segmentation fault error points to `return count + count_values(value, here) + count_values(value, current);`

```
typedef struct BinaryTree {
    int val;
    struct BinaryTree *left;
    struct BinaryTree *right;
} BinaryTree;

BinaryTree *build_tree(int value, BinaryTree *leftnode, BinaryTree *rightnode) {
    BinaryTree *out = calloc(1, sizeof(BinaryTree));
    out->val = value;
    out->leftnode = leftnode;
    out->rightnode = rightnode;

    return out;
}

int count_values(int value, BinaryTree *tree) {
  
    BinaryTree *current = tree;
    BinaryTree *here = current;
    int count = 0;

    if (current != NULL) {
        printf("Value in tree is not NULL\n");

        if (current->val < value) {
            printf("%d < %d\n", current->val, value);
            printf("Count value: %d\n", count);
            here = current->leftnode;
            count_values(value, here);
            current = current->rightnode;
            count_values(value, current);

        } else if (current->val == value) {
            printf("%d = %d\n", current->val, value);
            count++;
            printf("Count value: %d\n", count);
            here = current->leftnode;
            count_values(value, here);
            current = current->rightnode;
            count_values(value, current);
        } else {
            printf("%d > %d\n", current->val, value);
            count++;
            printf("Count value: %d\n", count);
            here = current->leftnode;
            count_values(value, here);
            current = current->rightnode;
            count_values(value, current);
        }
    }
        
    return count + count_values(value, here) + count_values(value, current);
}

int main(void) {
    BinaryTree *tree =
        build_tree(14, build_tree(3, NULL, NULL),
                   build_tree(15, NULL, build_tree(42, NULL, NULL)));

    //path is 14->15->42
    int count = count_values(42, tree);
    printf("should have a count of 1, got %d\n", count);

    count = count_values(14, tree);
    printf("should have a count of 3, got %d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code is incomplete. For example, `BinaryTree` definition is missing. Please provide a complete [mre].

Comment: `if (current->val != NULL)` That looks suspicious. `val` is not an pointer. Probably should be `if (current != NULL)`

Comment: @kaylum just included it at the very top, sorry about that!

Comment: @kaylum I tried `if (current != NULL)` but I still get a segmentation fault. When I run valgrind it points to the line `return count + count_values(value, here) + count_values(value, current);`

Comment: You're not adding the result of the recursive calls to `count`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters there are typos in the both functions as for example

```
out->leftnode = leftnode;
out->rightnode = rightnode;
```

and

```
here = current->leftnode;
current = current->rightnode;
```

You have to write

```
out->left = leftnode;
out->right = rightnode;
```

and

```
here = current->left;
current = current->right;
```

Within the function `count_values` already this if statement

```
if (current->val != NULL) {
```

invokes undefined behavior.

First of all it does not make a sense. And secondly before accessing data members of a node you need to check whether the pointer `current` (more precisely the pointer `tree`) is a null pointer or not.

Pay attention to that such statements like these

```
count_values(value, here);
count_values(value, current);
```

in fact have no effect.

The recursive function could be defined the following way

```
size_t count_values( const BinaryTree *tree, int value ) 
{
    return tree == NULL 
        ? 0 
        : ( tree->val >= value ) + count_values( tree->left, value ) + count_values( tree->right, value );
}
```

The pointer to the tree should be the first function parameter and declared with the qualifier `const` because the function does not change the tree. And the function should return an object of an unsigned integer type because the counter can not be a negative value. Instead of the return type `size_t` you may use for example the type `unsigned int`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct BinaryTree {
    int val;
    struct BinaryTree *left;
    struct BinaryTree *right;
} BinaryTree;

BinaryTree *build_tree(int value, BinaryTree *leftnode, BinaryTree *rightnode) {
    BinaryTree *out = calloc(1, sizeof(BinaryTree));
    out->val = value;
    out->left = leftnode;
    out->right = rightnode;

    return out;
}

size_t count_values( const BinaryTree *tree, int value ) 
{
    return tree == NULL 
        ? 0 
        : ( tree->val >= value ) + count_values( tree->left, value ) + count_values( tree->right, value );
} 

int main(void) {
    BinaryTree *tree =
        build_tree(14, build_tree(3, NULL, NULL),
                   build_tree(15, NULL, build_tree(42, NULL, NULL)));

    //path is 14->15->42
    size_t count = count_values( tree, 42);
    printf("should have a count of 1, got %zu\n", count);

    count = count_values(tree, 14 );
    printf("should have a count of 3, got %zu\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
should have a count of 1, got 1
should have a count of 3, got 3
```

Comment: I tried changing it to `current != NULL` and I get the same segmentation fault error. Which part doesn't make sense?

Comment: @firstlast You need initially check whether treee is a null pointer and if so return 0 from the function. See my function definition.

Answer (score 0):

You're making this way harder than it needs to be.

First test for the base case by testing whether `tree` is `NULL`.

If not, recurse on the left and right nodes, and add these counts to the count for the current node.

```
int count_values(int value, BinaryTree *tree) {
    if (tree == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    int count = tree->val >= value;
    count += count_values(value, tree->left);
    count += count_values(value, tree->right);

    return count;
}
```

Comment: This returns 0 for both test cases in the main function.

Comment: @firstlast See my updates of the Barmar answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Why did you change `>=` to `==`? The question says **a number greater than or equal to the value specified**. The rest of the edits look correct.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, I am sorry. It is my mistake.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yeah, I tried it with your changes, it also gives 0.

Comment: @firstlast There was a typo in my function. This expression ( tree->val >= value ) must be in parentheses. See my updated answer.

Comment: @firstlast Also see the demonstration program in my answer.

Comment: @Barmar Shouldn't the first test be `if (tree == NULL)`?

Comment: @SteveSummit Yes, that's right.

Comment: Yes, I just fixed that, and changed the comparison back to `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

1. In `if (current->val != NULL) {` current->value can never be NULL pointer as value isn't pointer. It is just int. You probably should check `current` instead of `current->val`
2. Even if you corrected that line your's program would segfault cause to stack overflow (hehe) because you unconditionally call your function from itself in `return count + count_values(value, here) + count_values(value, current);` line

P.S. the code you posted needed some adjustments to build. Fix it if you can